# Non-linear fit in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I have a set of data:

```r
x<- c(0.00100000, 0.08977778, 0.17855556, 0.26733333, 0.35611111, 0.44488889, 0.53366667, 0.62244444, 0.71122222)
y <- c(0.094982692, 0.074529874, 0.051782003, 0.026081288, -0.003576486, -0.038845028, -0.082764061, -0.141998524, -0.141998524)
```

and I wanted to fit a logarithmic curve to the data (`y = c*naturalLog(x + k) + d`). I tried nls in R ( which was as useful as tits on a fish). I also tried to fit exponential, with no sucess (fit was very bad). My question is, can you see a logarithmic or exponential correlation in the data? My end goal is to find the correlation coefficients, so I can transform y and make the correlation linear.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you try `nls`? What makes you say it was useless -- error or warning (what did it say) or bad fit or something else?

Comment: Plotting your data it looks basically linear - is there a reason you think that models as widely different as exponential and logarithmic would be better fits than linear? And if you're interested in correlation coefficients, why are you fitting models at all instead of just using `cor()`?

Comment: nls fit was terrible.  Regarding the cor(), I need to establish some sort of correlation first, then get the coefficients. It's tempting to proceed with linear, but data has a non-linear look (just by eyeballing).

Comment: Strong disagree that your data has a "non-linear look". `ggplot(data.frame(x, y), aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm")`, the R^2 of `lm(y~x)` is 0.97. I never see real data this linear.

Comment: ...compare to a log-transformed x, `ggplot(data.frame(x, y), aes(log(x), y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm")` and it's no surprise at all that `nls` didn't work. Your data look very linear, and not at all logarithmic.

Comment: @kaveh - In data science; I think context is important ; What are you measuring? what scientific question are you trying to answer ?  Since your final datapoint seems so at odds with the rest; can you get more measurements around it ? is it a valid datapoint ?

Comment: @GregorThomas, R-squared looks nice since the number of data is low.  My original data is over 1000, and a lot of them have 0.6-0.8 x values (it has the same look, so I only provided a subset). After x=0.4, more or less, y deviates from the linear pattern. This is very similar to logarithmic behaviour, so I was looking to fit the log. It might help to mention the data are the death rate (x) and growth rate (y) of a population. So usually things are not supposed to be linear.

Comment: That's very good context to have. **Could you please share the `nls` code you used?** It's much easier to help with coding problems if you share the code that has the problem. Conversely, if you want help picking a model, not with coding, I would suggest migrating the question to stats.stackexchange.com. That is the place to go for statistical help, Stack Overflow is for programming/coding help.

Comment: @GregorThomas m <- nls(1-x ~ a * log(y + b) , data = df, start = list(a = 1, b = 1), nls.control(maxiter = 500)) . Instead of x (death rate), I used 1-x (birth rate).

Comment: Some advice for getting help in the future. Missing/misleading in your question include (a) no code (b) data provided is not complete (this is good, but tell us there is more data!) (c) the data in your question looks linear; it's your larger data that doesn't look linear, (d) you have a theoretical reason why a linear model would be a bad fit, (e) you said your model is `y = c*naturalLog(x + k) + d`, but turnos out you weren't using `y` (or even a function of `y`!) as the response, rather `1 - x` is the response. In the future, please try to provide more relevant info from the start!

Comment: I'm confused; I put y in the formula; am I using nls incorrectly?

Comment: @GregorThomas Omg, I guess I messed up the dependent with my independent variables. Let me check...

Comment: @GregorThomas Embarrassingly, I mixed up nls formula! Thanks for the heads-up. Please post your comment separately so I can approve it as the answer to my question., and sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've said that you used this code:

```
m <- nls(1-x ~ a * log(y + b) , data = df, start = list(a = 1, b = 1), nls.control(maxiter = 500))
```

> Instead of `x` (death rate), I used `1-x` (birth rate).

Normally we use `y` as the response, not `x`. Also be careful that `birth_rate = 1 - death_rate` is not generally true, rather survival rate is 1 minus death rate.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. It was my silly mistake to mix variables... Have a great day.

Comment: Glad we got to the bottom of it :) Next time share your code in the question!

Answer (score 2):

This Weibull-like curve fits in only 5 iterations:

```
fm <- nls(y ~ a + (1-a) * (1 - exp(b * x^c)), 
          data.frame(x, y), 
          start = list(a = 0.5, b = 1, c = 1))
fm
```

giving:

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ a + (1 - a) * (1 - exp(b * x^c))
   data: data.frame(x, y)
      a       b       c 
0.09653 0.37163 1.17432 
 residual sum-of-squares: 0.0009496

Number of iterations to convergence: 5 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 3.901e-06
```

The fit looks good:

```
plot(y ~ x)
lines(fitted(fm) ~ x, col = "red")
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. It turned out that I used nls incorrectly, and now the logarithmic curve looks good. In the context of my data, I'm expecting logarithmic correlation, and Weibull might be an overfit. But many thanks for the answer, I learned a new thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code

```
library(minpack.lm)

x <- c(0.00100000, 0.08977778, 0.17855556, 0.26733333, 0.35611111, 0.44488889, 0.53366667, 0.62244444, 0.71122222)
y <- c(0.094982692, 0.074529874, 0.051782003, 0.026081288, -0.003576486, -0.038845028, -0.082764061, -0.141998524, -0.141998524)

#Create a data frame
df <- data.frame(x, y)

#Write the equation
nls.eq <- as.formula(y ~ (c*log(x + k) + d))

#Fitting equation using minpack.lm package
nls.out <- nlsLM(nls.eq, 
                 data = df,
                 start=list(c=1, k=1, d=1),
                 control  = nls.lm.control(maxiter = 500),
                 algorithm = "LM")
```

Comment: `cbind.data.frame(x, y)` is a worse way to write `data.frame(x, y)`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method to fit the logarithmic function :

[image]

[image]

The general principle of the method used is explained in : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales The fitting isn't wrt the equation model but wrt a linear integral equation to which the equation model is solution. In the present case the linear integral equation is : [image]. This avoid iterative calculus and no need for "guessed" initial values of the parameters.